# Gradle robolectric project works on OSX computer but not on Linux

Tags: linux, macos, gradle, robolectric

I'm using the same version of Gradle, 1.7 jdk thus not exactly the same version.

The main complain of the testing is :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/DependenciesTask Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DependenciesTask

I've tried to clean gradle cache in order to re download all dependencies.
Also i've tried to clean the project.

This didn't work.

What variables can affect the execution of a gradle test ?

To me there is:

- Gradle itself
- Java version of the sdk
- Internet connections problems

What else can be interfering ? **Are plugin versions platform dependant** ?

```
Executing task ':robolectric-tests:test' (up-to-date check took 0.432 secs) due to:
  Output file /home/ec2-user/repositories/MyProject/robolectric-tests/build/test-results has changed.
  Output file /home/ec2-user/repositories/MyProject/robolectric-tests/build/reports/tests has changed.
  Output file /home/ec2-user/repositories/MyProject/robolectric-tests/build/test-results/binary/test has changed.
Starting process 'Gradle Test Executor 1'. Working directory: /home/ec2-user/repositories/MyProject/robolectric-tests Command: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_72/bin/java -Djava.security.manager=jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.child.BootstrapSecurityManager -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=ES -Duser.language=ca -Duser.variant -ea -cp /home/ec2-user/.gradle/caches/2.3/workerMain/gradle-worker.jar jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain 'Gradle Test Executor 1'
Successfully started process 'Gradle Test Executor 1'
Gradle Test Executor 1 started executing tests.
Gradle Test Executor 1 finished executing tests.

com.tubtale.MyProject.robolectrictests.tests.RobTMyAndroidClassTest > testWhenActivityCreatedHelloTextViewIsVisible2 FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/DependenciesTask

        Caused by:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DependenciesTask

com.tubtale.MyProject.robolectrictests.tests.RobTMyAndroidClassTest > testWhenActivityCreatedHelloTextViewIsVisible FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/DependenciesTask

2 tests completed, 2 failed
Finished generating test XML results (0.217 secs) into: /home/ec2-user/repositories/MyProject/robolectric-tests/build/test-results
Generating HTML test report...
Finished generating test html results (0.11 secs) into: /home/ec2-user/repositories/MyProject/robolectric-tests/build/reports/tests
:robolectric-tests:test FAILED
:robolectric-tests:test (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 4.005 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':robolectric-tests:test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/ec2-user/repositories/MyProject/robolectric-tests/build/reports/tests/index.html

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':robolectric-tests:test'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:306)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/ec2-user/repositories/MyProject/robolectric-tests/build/reports/tests/index.html
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.handleTestFailures(Test.java:1118)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.executeTests(Test.java:549)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 44 more


BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: What about repositories config? Are you including mavenCentral or something similar in your build file?

Comment: Alex Florescu , i'm having the same build file for both projects in fact one is a exact copy of the other

Comment: That's fine, but it's not what I'm asking :) If you don't have that setup correctly, in one environment it could work because the dependency is already cached locally, whereas in the other one it's not and your build has no way of getting it.

Comment: It is linked to Gradle Issue https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3243

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I also ran into this issue on Linux but not OSX. I found a work-around by adding

> org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3

to my 'testCompile' dependencies.

```
dependencies {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testCompile 'org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3'
  testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
  testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
}
```

I don't know why maven-ant-tasks isn't getting fetched on linux. It appears to be a valid dependency of robolectric.

Comment: I think after I tried to migrate to `1.1.0 android gradle` plugin I also got same behavior

Comment: @EugenMartynov Are you still seeing this? Did you change your `androidTestCompile` to `testCompile`? try `gradlew clean testDebug`?

Comment: I changed `androidTestCompile` to `testCompile` as well did cleaning several times. It might be related for Jake Wharton `sdk-manager` plugin. I will check later evening

Comment: @EugenMartynov Let me know. I am also using that and this has solved my issues.

Answer (score 7):

The selected answer is correct, and also applies when upgrading Gradle from 2.2.1 to 2.3 on OSX. If you don't add the dependency for `testCompile 'org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3'` then Robolectric tests will fail when the Gradle version is 2.3.

Also noteworthy is that I have a separate module for my Robolectric tests, so I added the new dependency to the `build.gradle` file in my Robolectric module, NOT my Android app module.

Just got a new Mac, so my old Mac & new Mac are side by side, while I configure the new one. I used Homebrew to build up my new Mac, and wasn't aware that Gradle 2.3 had just been released... That's why the Robolectric tests worked on my old Mac (with Gradle 2.2.1) but not on my new Mac (with Gradle 2.3).

Comment: You're absolutely right. I ran into this error when running test directly use gradle(2.3) on my Mac, but no problem when using the project's gradle wrapper(2.2.1).